# which is the correct option for below gap?

Tags: grammar

I am trying to find which one is the correct for below.

The new drug...at the last conference is expected to ease the suffering of a lot of patients

A.introduced
OR
B. which has introduced

Comment: You can say either 'introduced' or 'which _was_ introduced' (not _has_).

Comment: thank you very much !